# ReactJS onClick handler in map return undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to add a handler on `<a>` in `map`:

*My simple functions:*

```
getFacilities = (e) => {
    console.log(e)
}
```

*In render:*

```
    const items = this.state.data;
    let result = items.map(function(value, i){
        return (
            <List.Item key={i}>
               <a onClick={this.getFacilities}>{value.user.name}</a>
            </List.Item>
        );
    });
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getFacilities' of undefined

There are many topics with this error, Almost all of them use this as solution:

I add this in `constructor`

```
this.getFacilities = this.getFacilities.bind(this)
```

But it not working in my case and still return same error. it's simple, confused can not figure out what I missed I done wrong.

Comment: make your callback function inside `.map()` an arrow function for `this` to refer to your component

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key thing to note is the difference between normal function expressions and the new ES6 arrow functions. In short: unlike function expressions arrow functions do not maintain their own `this` (or `arguments`) - they borrow it from the outer lexical environment.

> "[An arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) is a syntactically compact alternative to a regular function expression, although without its own bindings to the this, arguments, super, or new.target keywords. Arrow function expressions are ill suited as methods, and they cannot be used as constructors."

So when you refer to `this` in that `map` callback `this` doesn't refer to the class.

So 1) change the function expression to an arrow function:

```
let result = items.map((value, i) => {
  return (
    <List.Item key={i}>
      <a onClick={this.getFacilities}>{value.user.name}</a>
    </List.Item>
  );
});
```

2) Since you're using an arrow function for your class method you can remove as this would only be required if you were using a standard class method definition rather than a class field.

```
this.getFacilities = this.getFacilities.bind(this);
```

*However* there's some evidence to suggest that class fields (using arrow functions) such as these [are worse than using standard class method format](https://medium.com/@charpeni/arrow-functions-in-class-properties-might-not-be-as-great-as-we-think-3b3551c440b1), so you may be better off keeping the binding in the constructor and using the standard format for functions that you're passing around:

```
getFacilities(e) {
  console.log(e)
}
```

It's something to bear in mind.

---

PS, from that link:

> "It is unnecessary to do that to every function. This is just as bad as autobinding (on a class). You only need to bind functions that you pass around. e.g. `onClick={this.doSomething}`. Or `fetch.then(this.handleDone)` — Dan Abramov‏"

Answer (score 1):

Because `this` inside your map function is not defined. Use an arrow function to bind the map function to the parent scope:

```
const items = this.state.data;
let result = items.map((value, i) => {
    return (
        <List.Item key={i}>
           <a onClick={this.getFacilities}>{value.user.name}</a>
        </List.Item>
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To ensure proper binding of `this`, use arrow function in the `map` callback:

```
  let result = items.map((value, i) => {
        return (
            <List.Item key={i}>
               <a onClick={this.getFacilities}>{value.user.name}</a>
            </List.Item>
        );
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please dont use Arrow function

```
class Name extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.getFacilities = this.getFacilities.bind(this);
  }

  getFacilities(e) {
    // remove Arrow function
    console.log(e);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.data.map(function(value, i) {
          return (
            <List.Item key={i}>
              <a onClick={this.getFacilities}>{value.user.name}</a>
            </List.Item>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as `onClick` is attached inside `map`.

Comment: @Clarity please check now

Comment: This will have the original error because `this` binding is incorrect.

Comment: @Clarity He is using Arrow function with bind so changed Arrow function to normal function

Comment: Have you actually tried running your code and verifying that it works?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203519/discussion-between-jay-vaghasiya-and-clarity).

Answer (score -1):

You need to change `map` predicate to **arrow function** (to bind the `this` context to your component not to the `map` function)

```
 let result = items.map((value, i) => {
        return (
            <List.Item key={i}>
               <a onClick={this.getFacilities}>{value.user.name}</a>
            </List.Item>
        );
    });
```

After that, you need to change the `getFacilities` declaration

**Solution 1** - Remove this line from constructor

```
this.getFacilities = this.getFacilities.bind(this)
```

**Solution 2** - But if you want, you can change `getFacilities`to **hoisting function**

```
getFacilities(e) {
    console.log(e)
}
```

And keep this line in constructor

```
this.getFacilities = this.getFacilities.bind(this)
```